# DynamoDB table to Cloudwatch Graph

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a DynamoDB table and I am querying using one of my GSI some condition.
Now what I want is to graph everything that this query returns in CloudWatch
Is that possible?

Also DynamoDB has this limitation of only showing a max of 300 items at the time. Can I at least see the total of items the query is returning?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you will need to process the DynamoDB query and writes to CloudWatch through a separate process.

A single [Query operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression.

For a given [query operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), the *COUNT* (number of items evaluated before any QueryFilter is applied) as well a the *ScannedCount* (the number of matching items before the filter was applied) are returned.